# How to return window.performance object to CasperJS scope

Tags: coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to return window.performance object from the web page back to casper's scope with the following code but I'm getting null. Can someone explain why?

```
    performance = casper.evaluate ->
        return window.performance
    @echo performance
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.x doesn't implement `window.performance`, so you can't use it.

PhantomJS 2.0.0 implements it, but it doesn't implement the `window.performance.toJSON()` function. The problem with PhantomJS is that you have to access this information through [`evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), but it has the following limitation:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

You will have to find your own way of serializing this in the page context and passing it to the outside (JavaScript):

```
var performance = casper.evaluate(function(){
    var t = window.performance.timing;
    var n = window.performance.navigation;
    return {
        timing: {
            connectStart: t.connectStart,
            connectEnd: t.connectEnd,
            ...
        },
        navigation: {
            type: n.type,
            redirectCount: n.redirectCount
        },
        ...
    };
});
```

or look for a deep copy algorithm that produces a serializable object ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1891377/1816580)):

```
var perf = casper.evaluate(function(){
    function cloneObject(obj) {
        var clone = {};
        for(var i in obj) {
            if(typeof(obj[i])=="object" && obj[i] != null)
                clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
            else
                clone[i] = obj[i];
        }
        return clone;
    }
    return cloneObject(window.performance);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(perf, undefined, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean I can't use it for PhantomJS 1.9.x? If I could just serialize it within the page context and return the JSON object doesn't it not matter what the version of phantom is? Like I could retrieve window.performance.timing.value fine

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x simply doesn't have `window.performance`, so there is nothing to serialize.

Comment: But if the code isnt everything being executed on the page that phantom's at? If what you are saying is true I shouldnt be able to retrieve any values from window.performance.timing right?

Comment: Yes. Are you able to retrieve some values from `window.performance.timing` when using PhantomJS 1.9.x? If so, how?

Comment: I'm just putting in evaluate what I would put in at the JavaScript console and returning the results. So if I serialize everything in the JavaScript console and just pass the JSON object  it should be fine?

Comment: For example the issue that I have is also with chrome. Just typing in performance or performance.timing returns an unserialized Object

Comment: Yes, you can put everything in an actual object and pass it out of the page context. Have you tried any of the snippets I provided?

Comment: I'm about to try them but i can't seem to duplicate the time i retrieved the value... I see what you mean though, you are saying PhantomJS 1.9.x as a browser itself doesn't have that performance feature?